# Adjective for a community which deliberately distances itself from others and becomes hostile

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is an adjective for a community (often a minority) which deliberately distances itself from other communities (the majority), potentially for reasons such as discrimination, ostracisation?

You may say:

> Due to increasing tensions, this ethnic community has become more ____.

I am specifically looking for a word which conveys hostility towards other communities (violence, etc)

Comment: isolationist https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/isolationist : this implies a **deliberate** policy of isolating oneself from others.  If it's more accidental then you could simply say "isolated".

Comment: Sorry @MaxWilliams I've updated my question - looking for something which displays hostility

Comment: Isolationist is hostile - think USA in the '30s

Comment: Are these compatible ideas? Can I be aggressively hostile if I'm deliberately  isolating myself? If I'm only hostile in a reactionary way, I'm just being defensive, no? Either way, can I be violent if I'm isolated?

Answer (score 1):

Consider **insular**, which the [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/insular) defines (for both American and British usage) as follows:

> ... interested only in your own country or group and not willing to accept
>   different or foreign ideas

Answer (score 0):

Another word for **isolationist** might be **autarkic**, although I am not sure all dictionaries would recognise the word as an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the word **estranged** or **self-estranged** could work.

> **estranged**
>
> no longer friendly; alienated

[thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/estranged)